# Cleaning up the general topic tags

Tags: discussion, faq, tags

There are various general topic tags like [zombies](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zombies), [vampires](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vampires), [sex](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sex), [fight](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fight), [technology](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technology) or [revenge](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/revenge). Those serve primarily for either tagging identification questions or general questions about the depiction of those topics in movies. However, I don't see much use in creating a tag for each and every single totally generic topic a movie could be about. **This is simply a tag granularity that does not fit to the scope of this site, this is not Everything.SE, it's Movies.SE** and I'm not sure we want tags for e.g. [cars](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cars), [refridgerators](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/refridgerators) or [nazis](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nazis) simply because those things can be depicted in movies.

For identification questions we already have genre tags as further specification and I can't see people here looking for identification questions specifically about revenge or zombies. I see that even on our site there can be very well interesting and good questions about sex or vampires, specifically about their depiction and treatment inside movies and TV, but **those also fit equally well into other *movie-related* tag categories**, like [reception](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reception), [analysis](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/analysis), [first-appearance](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/first-appearance) or [movie-rating](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/movie-rating).

This problem has been adressed a [very long time ago](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/73/49) where the respective tags got removed and in a [more specific, yet unresolved, question](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1068/49) about the [revenge](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/revenge) tag in particular. It has also been adressed in a [very related question](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/952/49) about the [aliens](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aliens) tag (though, there the main problem was that there was also the specific movie-meaning of the tag).

But in light of the bigger [recent tag cleanup proposal](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1733/49), that I don't completely agree with in its entirety, I'd still make an effort for **drawing a clear line *somewhere*, and general *non-movie-related* tags is exactly that line we shouldn't cross**. Allowing tags for each and every general topic depicted *in* movies but *not directly related to* movies would just open the tagging system to an arbitrary explosion of unhandlable tags and divert from the core topic of our sites. I'd thus hereby generally **propose the removal and prohibition of such overly generic topic tags unrelated to movies and TV**. I already adressed that at the end of [my broader answer](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1735/49) to the tag cleanup question, which seemed to have met some agreement, but would propose this here in a more canonical and condensed form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Yes!

I agree with this entirely and we should remove these tags!

For clarity, a full list of tags effected by this change (as far as I can see) is as follows:

[fight](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fight), [zombies](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zombies), [vampires](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vampires), [technology](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technology), [sex](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sex)

<sub>Note that if it's not included in the list and falls under the description "general non-movie-related tags" this means I missed it, rather than excluded it</sub>

Comment: Well, those tags are already listed in the question (I removed the ones that don't exist anyway). And you also missed others from the question, like `revenge`.

Comment: In favor of removing all of them, except *technology* which seems tricky and is apparently a can of worms.

Answer (score -2):

As long as a tag is of interest to a group of people, I see no reason why the tag shouldn't exist to enable people to find what they are looking for. You could argue some of those tags are less useful than others, and we'd always want to encourage people to think about the particular tags they are using, but as long as they aren't duplicating existing tags, I think they are serving the exact purpose that tags were created for...meta data for people to find topics they are interested in.

Comment: Even if suggesting something I should better shut up about, it is my duty to illuminate you about the fact that if you don't agree with the proposal of this meta question (which you apparently don't), you should actually vote it down to show exactly that.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson you want us to vote the actual question or the answers?

Comment: It is a clear and defintie proposal with a clear proposed policy. Voting on it is definitely the way to go. Even without Flyk's answer those +8 are a sign that what is proposed in the question is unanimously agreed to by the community. If there are no answers the only thing to rely on is the question. That's just how meta voting works.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson gotcha. Vote recorded. Though I think it's a great question. (I wonder how many questions people disagree with get upvoted because they still think it's a great question? :)