# Let's talk about [sex]

Tags: discussion, tags

I can't see that this tag would ever be used for any purpose other than "having another tag on it". Do we really need a [sex](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sex) tag? Wouldn't the fact that the question is obviously about sex be enough?

Comment: I am not much in favour for this deletion but i think few question tagged with it doesn't doing fair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[sex](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sex) has been cleaned up as part of [Cleaning up the general topic tags](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1428/5603)

Answer (score 1):

I don't necessarily disagree. However put a bit of a perspective on it I think its meant to be used when a question is about sex in movies in general, rather that just another tag alongside a movie name.

What should someone tag the following:

[Exceptions to horror genre and female sexuality tropes?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/23477/exceptions-to-horror-genre-and-female-sexuality-tropes)

For the purpose of having something for people to vote on here - I would propose keeping the tag for the purpose of tagging questions that specifically relate to the use of sex in a movie or TV show.

Comment: Surely you would tag that as [tag:tropes] [tag:horror]

Comment: @Flyk - but you recently edited a question to add a 'profanity' tag to it.  Why is profanity ok, and sex not ok?

Comment: [The use case for profanity seems narrow enough that this should just be merged into dialogue in my opinion](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/a/1686/5603).

Comment: I agree with this; someone who wants to participate in Qs related to sex would not have to *know* what canon they should look in, they can just take the shortcut of the sex tag. A Q which relates to sex might not have the actual word "sex" in it; how would a person find that?